# How to use recursive methods with lists

Tags: java, recursion, arraylist

I have a small problem with wrapping my head around how to use recursive methods to count the number of elements in a list, then jumping to each element in that list and count how many elements they have stored. I will try to generalize this as much as possible, but I will use an example of my own. 
The data structure that I have, is an arraylist where I have stored elements. All of these each have an arraylist where the elements pointing to this element is stored by the preceding elements ID. So: Element->List->ID (Integer, ie. 2)-> Element nr.2. I want to count how many preceding elements there is for each element, by recursive methods. I have tried a couple of options, like storing all of the preceding elements in a new list and then give the size of this as the number of preceding elements, as well as using a counter-int. The closest I have gotten so far is using this method(id is a number always +1 the index it is located in the arraylist containing it):

```
private int getPredecessorCount(int id){
    for(int i:elementList[id-1].predecessors){
        return 1+getPredecessorCount(i);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This gives me correct answer for all the elements where the elements contains a list with only a single element. I cannot get it to work with the elements having lists with more than 1 predecessorelement. Any ideas?

I also tried:

```
    private int getPredecessorCount(int id, int counter) {
    if(!elementList[id-1].predecessors.isEmpty()){
        for(int i : elementList[id-1].predecessors){
            counter+=getPredecessorCount(i, counter);
            counter++;
        }   
    }
    return counter;
```

This gives me somewhat the same result as the previous one, but where the previous one gave me too few predecessors for the ones who contained larger lists, this one gives me wildly too many.

Comment: Your `for` loop will never look at more than one predecessor, because the first thing it does is leave the method (with the `return` statement).  What did you really want to do in the `for` loop, add all the `getPredecessorCount`s?

Comment: A recursive method with a loop in it is a strange beast.

Comment: I'm unclear what your list contains, and what answer you're looking for.

Comment: I'm sorry if I were unclear anywhere. It contains objects (which I in this question labeled "elements") 
It is as ajb says, I'm looking for a way to add all the getpredecessorsCounts. The elements contains a list of other elements which precedes the first. This list might contain several elements, so it must iterate through everyone all the way down.

Comment: Your first issue is that a person would usually use recursion OR looping as an iterative approach to solving some problem - not both. Your second problem is that when you are using recursion, you need some termination condition for the case where there's nothing left to recurse through.

Comment: I did know your first argument, which is why I asked the question. I wanted to see if it was possible to do with lists as well. The second... well, shouldn't it be just to check that the next element is not null?

Answer (score 0):

Ok lets generalise this ...

```
private int counter(List<Element> items) {

   int count = 0;
   for (Element item: items) {
       count ++; // for the item counting
       if (item.holdsElements) { // for inner elements
           count = count + counter(item.getElements());
       }
   }

   return count;
}
```

I have intentionally written a simplified version of this method to illustrate how this should be done. Null checks and other edge cases are ignored by purpose.

So you count all elements in a list ... ok simple enough, and if an element contains inner items you go and count those. Then return the absolute count.

Your problem was that you returned the result once you got the count from the first element, not considering the others. Problems as this can be easily spotted with the use of the debugger.